# Build android app via maven android plugin apk installation error

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to build an Android app via maven android plugin. I have used multi-dex=true in pom file. I already tried using forcejumbo=true.
Also googled on it. Didn't find satisfactory answer.
I am getting error while installing apk file.

When I install it from cmd it gives error :

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

When I tried to install it from my email on device it gives error :

> E/dex2oat(11177): Failed to open dex from file descriptor for zip file
>   '/data/app/com.xx.yyy-1/base.apk': Failed to open dex file
>   '/data/app/com.xx.yyy-1/base.apk' from memory: Unrecognized magic
>   number in /data/app/com.xx.yyy-1/base.apk: P K

How do I fix this?

Why I used multi dex :

I was getting this error:

trouble writing output: Too many method references: 72545; max is 65536.
[INFO] You may try using --multi-dex option.
so used multi dex

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>

    <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
        <version>22_r1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>22.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nostra13.universalimageloader</groupId>
        <artifactId>universal-image-loader</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>    

                <exclusion>
                  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>r09</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
              <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                  <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                  <groupId>android</groupId>
                  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.1</version>
<exclusions>            
<exclusion>
          <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
          <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
      <version>v3-rev96-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.facebook.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>facebook-android-sdk</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
<systemPath>/home/mangospring/ms/mangoandroid/tags/2015_05_18_OC_V_1_4_5/libs/facebooksdk.jar</systemPath>


<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!--dependency>
  <groupId>fr.avianey</groupId>
  <artifactId>facebook-android-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.18.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.parse.bolts</groupId>
    <artifactId>bolts-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>25.0.0</version>
 <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: 1. Why use maven when there is Gradle? 2. Just use the android gradle plugin 3. Why are you using multidex? Show us your dependencies.

Comment: 1 and 2. We have very complex project structure. I tried using gradle it did not allow me to set up multiple hierarchy project.

3. I have to use multidex file beacause getting following error

trouble writing output: Too many method references: 72545; max is 65536.
[INFO] You may try using --multi-dex option.

Comment: Post to Stackoverflow, not a link.

Comment: Updated dependencies in post

Comment: I'd highly suggest learning how to use Gradle. What is that last dependency? `com.google.android.gms:google-play-services`? https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup